# returning bool& from vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

In the following code:

```
class SomeClass {
    vector<int> i;
    vector<bool> b;

public:
    int& geti() {return i[0];}
    bool& getb() {return b[0];}
};
```

If you comment out `getb()`, the code compiles fine. Apparently there's no problem returning a reference to an `int` that's stored in a vector, but you can't do it with a `bool`.

Why is this?

Comment: Taking into account existing replies, you can still "salvage" your code by using `std::vector<bool>::reference` as the return type for your function, instead of the explicit `bool&`. `std::vector<bool>::reference` would be that proxy class that acts as a generalized reference for packed `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is "special."  It stores its elements as a bit array, meaning that the elements are not individually addressable and you cannot obtain a reference to an element.

`std::vector<bool>` iterators, its `operator[]`, and its other member functions return *proxy objects* that provide access to the elements without requiring actual `bool` objects to be stored.

If you need to be able to access individual elements, consider using a `std::vector<char>` or defining a `bool`-like enumeration backed by a `char` (or a `signed char` or `unsigned char`, if you care about signedness).

Comment: +1 Nice catch... That didn't even cross my mind. I spent a min. thinking about references to locals and stuff...

Comment: That's incredibly irritating. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: IIRC `std::vector<bool>` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @JesseGood:  `std::vector<bool>` is not deprecated.

Comment: Okay, after googling it, it seems it was proposed, but the C++ standard committee shot it down.

Answer (score 2):

vector<**bool**> is a special class template specialization for the **bool** type.

This specialization is provided to optimize for space allocation: eight **bool** elements are combined to one byte and each bool element occupies only one bit.

Reference to one bit in certain one byte is not allowed.

So the function could not return the reference to the a **bool** type in vector<**bool**>.

Someone also thinks vector<**bool**> is not a container.

You can use deque<**bool**> instead.